# Mac shift select like windows

Tags: windows, mac, hotkeys

I am working on a Mac and would like to be able to shift select files like Windows.

So select one file, then hold shift, and select another file, and all the files in between are also selected.

Why is this behaviour not apparent on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finder you have to show your files in the list-view. It does not work in icons-view. I have just tested, and it works for me in macOS sierra 10.12.3.

Comment: that is lame lol